# Facebook has publish_actions but still throws (#100) No permission to publish the video for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following permissions in my code and Facebook has approved public_profile, publish_actions, publish_pages. How come I can programmatically publish a video for some users but for others they get a permission issue?

```
scope: 'email,publish_actions,publish_pages'
```

Upload code

```
  def start_upload
    response = request(upload_phase: :start, file_size: File.size("#{episode_file_path}"))
    if response.code == '200'
      @upload_session_id = JSON.parse(response.body)["upload_session_id"]
    else
      raise response.body
    end
  end

  def transfer_upload
    response =JSON.parse(transfer_file)
    if response["start_offset"] != response["end_offset"]
      raise response
    end
  end

  def finish_upload
    response = request(upload_phase: :finish, title: @title, description: @description)
    if response.code != '200'
      raise response.body
    end
  end

  def url
    "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/#{@post_id}/videos"
  end

  def episode_file_path
    "#{Rails.root}/public/episode_soundbite/#{@episode_id}/video.mp4"
  end

  def request(params)
    Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(url), params.merge(access_token: @oauth_token, upload_session_id: @upload_session_id))
  end

  def transfer_file
    command =  "curl -X POST \"#{url}\"  \
                      -F \"access_token=#{@oauth_token}\" \
                      -F \"upload_phase=transfer\" \
                      -F \"start_offset=0\" \
                      -F \"upload_session_id=#{@upload_session_id}\" \
                      -F \"video_file_chunk=@#{episode_file_path}\""

    response = ''
    IO.popen('-') { |p|
      if p.nil? then
        $stderr.close
         exec command
      end
      response  = p.read
    }
    return response
  end
```

Comment: The user may choose not to grant that permission to your app. You need to handle that case

Comment: I asked a user if they did that, they sent me a screen shot of the public_action enabled on their facebook account but it still did not work for them. Do I need manage_pages permission?

Comment: If you want to publish to a page, you need manage_pages.

Comment: That ended up being the answer. Not sure why some users were still able to publish to a page with the public_posts option and why others needed the manage_pages option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add manage_pages to the scope